# Clear Text in RichTextBox in C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox, visual-studio-express

I have a RichTextBox, and I am wanting to code it, that when the user left clicks in the box, that the text in that text box, clears out.

Please can someone help me out?

My code I have tried is:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.text = "";
}
```

At the moment I have the box with "Input Text Here" written in it (under the Text in the Properties Section) - so when the user clicks inside the box, it will clear that text,so the user can type text in there.

Thank you.

Comment: What should happen if the user doesn't use the mouse and just tab keys the RichTextBox into focus?

Comment: Or if the user changes the text to something he wants?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
private void richTextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (richTextBox1.Text == "Input Text Here")
  {
    richTextBox1.Clear();
    richTextBox1.Focus();
  }
}
```

It checks wether default text is there or not, if it is it clears it and gives the richbox focus so you can enter text. Otherwise, it procedes with the regular textchanging.

Comment: Tell me if you need help, remember, ofcourse replace my object names with yours etc.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to MouseClick of rtb, then do:

```
    private void richTextBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            richTextBox1.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you want to clear the text on *every* left mouse click! :)

Comment: You right, I don't want to clear it on every mouse click, but the main reason for this program is not to save the input text, but to use it when it is in the box - This program is a tool to convert text into readable text. So I have an input text box on the left and a readable list box on the right, with a button in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I am VS2015 user.

```
richTextBox1.Clear();                 // Form
richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear(); // WPF
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a Cue Textbox. You can do this with one WINAPI call.

See this as a reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18858/Fully-themed-Windows-Vista-Controls

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

Go to the "properties" of your richtextbox. You will see a yellow lightning bolt in the first line tab. There you will find all possible events that can be triggered. Search for "Enter" or "Click" entry, double-click it. There you can put whatever you want (such as richTextBox1.Text = "";)